# How to open php project in NetBeans - don't have php category to select

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I've started using NetBeans and I'm trying to create a new project from existing files - on a server. But when I click on new project -> I don't have option to select php project.

here's the screenshot:

[image: netbeans]

Answer (score 1):

You should download NetBeans for PHP

Comment: Is there any other IDE that I could use? I don't like NetBeans.

Comment: Netbeans is good enought, also you can use Webmatrix but I prefer Netbeans